# how to do fix point multiplication considering corner case

Tags: c

I'm new to C language. I want to ask about how to Implement C function to multiply two 8-bit signed fixed point numbers. Function should also check corner case of Signed x Signed multiply. Truncate the result of multiplication to 8-bits. When I do use multiplication function with corner points it gives following errors

> error C2224: left of '.real' must have struct/union type 
>       IntelliSense: expression must have class type
>       error C2224: left of '.imag' must have struct/union type

As I am new in C, so I can't exactly understand the error messages. Here is my code what I'm trying to write. Can't resolve it:

```
typedef struct COMPLEX 
{
    short real;
    short imag;
}COMPLEX;   

COMPLEX ComplexMultFixed(COMPLEX z1, COMPLEX z2); 

char multiplied(char z1, char z2)    
{
    short  c;
    int i,j;
    short   L1,L2;
    char ans;
    COMPLEX out;
    int overflow;
    c = z1 * z2;

    if (c != 0x4000)
    {
        c *=2;
    }
    else
    {
        overflow = 1;
        c  = 0x7fff;
    }

    L1 = z1.real * z2.real;
    L2 = z1.imag * z2.imag;     // Rounding and truncation
    out.real = (((L1 - L2)+0x0040)>>7);
    L1 =  z1.real * z2.imag;
    L2 =  z1.imag * z2.real;
    // Rounding and truncation
    out.imag = (((L1 + L2)+0x0040)>>7);
    return(ans);
}
```

Comment: `char multiplied(char z1, char z2)`...  `L1 = z1.real * z2.real;` , `L2 = z1.imag * z2.imag;` : `z1` and `z2` is `char`, not `COMPLEX`

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is some confusion in two functions below..

```
COMPLEX ComplexMultFixed(COMPLEX z1, COMPLEX z2); 

char multiplied(char z1, char z2)    
{
```

Are they same for you? To me it should be same..

Change type from `char` to `COMPLEX`

```
COMPLEX multiplied(COMPLEX z1, COMPLEX z2)
```